# How to detect if Safari is disabled on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, safari

How can you detect whether Safari has been disabled by parental controls on the iPhone? I know it is possible because the App X3Watch refuses to work until Safari is disabled. As far as I can see there is no api for the parental controls, so what technique can be used for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but is OS3.0 and later, you can detect if a URL can be opened by any application on the system using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:myURL]`.  I'll betcha it will return `NO` if Safari is disabled.

Comment: Does this still work? I tried this on iOS 6 (iPad 3), but it returns YES even if Safari is disabled in Restrictions. However, if I actually call openURL:, Safari does NOT open when disabled, as expected.

Comment: To answer my own question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771177/uiapplications-canopenurl-openurl-return-misleading-result)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to include the solution to this in a view controller. The two bools need to be used because a user can open an external program independently of safari when the view is loaded, but the button that needs safari hasn't been opened yet.

```
@implementation ViewController {
@private BOOL externalProgramOpened;
@private BOOL buttonPressed;
}

-(void) setExternalProgramOpened {
    // Only set to yes if we're trying to open safari
    if(buttonPressed) {
        externalProgramOpened = YES;
    }
}

-(void) notifyUserOfRestrictedAccess {

    if(externalProgramOpened == NO) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Safari Needs to be enabled!"
                                    message:@"It looks like the Safari browser is
                                              disabled. Please enable it 
                                              (Settings>General>Restrictions) in order to 
                                              continue."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    } else {
        externalProgramOpened = NO;
    }

    buttonPressed = NO;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    externalProgramOpened = NO;
    buttonPressed = NO;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(setExternalProgramOpened)
                                          name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                          object:nil];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                          name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    buttonPressed = YES;

    NSString * URL = *someURL*;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    [self performSelector:@selector(notifyUserOfRestrictedAccess) withObject:self 
               afterDelay:.75];
}
```